# How to remove the leading and trailing space from each line of a file using shell script?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with some leading and trailing spaces. Here is the file

```
val1=22 
 val2=23  
val4=34
```

How can I remove both the leading and trailing white space from it? The white space could be a 'tab' too. Is there a single command to do it?

Comment: Do you have any special utility in concern?

Comment: nope. Any utility like sed, awk but that should not be a performance culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the command I found to remove both the leading and trailing spaces and tabs from every line of a file. It works for me.

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' "filename"
```

Where

- s/ : Substitute command ~ replacement for pattern (^[ \t]*) on each addressed line
- ^[ \t]* : Search pattern ( ^ – start of the line; [ \t]* match one or more blank spaces including tab)
- // : Replace (delete) all matched pattern

Credit goes to this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-leading-spaces-from-front-of-each-word.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have a very wide variety of options to achieve the desired result. One of them is simply to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), one of the best text editors around:

- Open your file in Notepad++,
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Replace" dialog box,
- Insert the `(^[\s\t]+)|([\s\t]+$)` in the "Find what" text box,
- Leave the "Replace with" text box blank,
- Select the "Regular expression" in the "Search Mode" group at the bottom of the dialog box.
- Press the "Replace All" button and you're done.

---

The code inserted in the "Find what" text box is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that instructs the finder to find the leading (`^[\s\t]+`) or trailing (`[\s\t]+$`) spaces or tabs.